# How could I resolve this error?

Tags: boot

I was using my laptop and it suspended automatically and as I tried to log it I couldn't type the password, as I rebooted the device, this screen is coming and the system freezes again.
How could I resolve this? It's very urgent.! [image: screen image]

Comment: There's no error on that screen, so check out [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/162075/301745)